# Fail to install PyOSG because of osgProducer linking error

Tags: python, opengl, ld, openscenegraph

I am trying to install the Python wrapper for OSG with `pip install PyOSG`.

But it failed with this error:

```
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Referenced.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Camera.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/RenderSurface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/KeyboardMouse.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/buildinfo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Block.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Keyboard.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Timer.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/VisualChooser.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/CameraConfig.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Producer.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/CameraGroup.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Trackball.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Events.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/InputArea.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Producer/Math.o -lboost_python -lOpenThreads -lProducer -lProducer -losg -losgDB -losgFX -losgGA -losgParticle -losgProducer -losgSim -losgUtil -losgText -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PyOSG/_Producer.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -losgProducer

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I've installed `Producer` which is dependent on by OSG, so I don't what else should I install to make the linking success.

Comment: have you restarted your computer since you installed Producer?  I sometimes get weird errors with ld that resolve themselves on restart.  It's weird.

Comment: @JeffTratner Restarted. Still failing ;(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! that's definitely frustrating. :-/ I wish I knew more about OSG specifically. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Producer is at least a couple years out of date, replaced by osgViewer and related classes, at least as far back as version 1.0, probably before then too.

Try looking for a newer version of PyOSG, or try one of the more active projects out there eg:

osgSWIG (which includes Python) http://code.google.com/p/osgswig/

osgboostpyton:  http://code.google.com/p/osgboostpython/

Good Luck!